# Why is the "Cofinal topology" a topology at all?

Tags: general-topology

The point-set topology book I'm studying from says that if $X$ is a set, and $\Gamma$ is a collection of subsets $G$ of $X$, such that $X-G$ is *finite*, then $(X,\Gamma)$ is a topological space, called the "cofinal" topology on $X$.

My question is if $X$ is infinite, $\phi \notin \Gamma$ as $X-\phi = X$ is infinite. Consequently, $\Gamma$ is not a topology on $X$?

What is wrong? (I know I'm making some stupid mistake. I apologize for being a newbie :) )

Comment: The book was careless. $\Gamma$ should be the set of subsets with finite complement, _along with_ the empty set. Also, $\Gamma$ is not _a_ collection of such $G$, it's _the_ collection of such $G$.

Comment: Oh. I was thinking about that small correction, seems like I thought right. :D Thanks!

Comment: you can use either \emptyset=$\emptyset$ or \varnothing=$\varnothing$ for the empty set symbol in LaTeX

Comment: Also this should be called the "cofin**ite**" topology - "cofin**al**" means [something quite different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality).

Comment: @NoahSchweber : "..called the cofinal topology..". Thats why I couldn't google it. Seems that paragraph was wrong about many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **co-finite** (not *cofinal*) topology on a set $X$ is $\{\emptyset\} \cup\{G: X-G \text{ finite }\}$. One can check this does form a topology on any set $X$.

Comment: The same as @Arthur said. Thanks!